# How to group in mongodb withtout including _id

Tags: mongodb

so I want to result as :

```
{
    "id" : 888789999,
    "name" : "Malaysian with Attendance Allowance",
}
```

but I tried

```
{$group : {
    'id' : '$profiles.id',
    'name' : {$first:'$profiles.name'},
}}
```

an I get an error :

> "errmsg" : "The field 'id' must be an accumulator object",

Comment: Following the `$group` operation with a `$replaceRoot` operation might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, to group by profile id and get first name, add project if you need id without underscore.

In group, except _id other fields should have accumulation or aggregation

```
{$group : {
    '_id' : '$profiles.id',
    'name' : {$first:'$profiles.name'},
}}
```

If you don't want to include _id then

```
{$group : {
        _id: null,
        'id' :  {$first:'$profiles.id'},// any accumulation which you need
        'name' : {$first:'$profiles.name'},
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
            id : { profiles: { $profiles: "$id" }},
name : {$first:{profiles:{$profiles:"name"}}}
        }
      }
   ]
)
```